# how to keep the y-axis labels in between the lines in HighChart plug in

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

i am using [this](http://www.highcharts.com/) plugin to create the chart .

i have this :[image]

and this is what i want:

[image]

how can i do this? Any references??

and here is my code for this chart

```
$(function () 
{
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 100]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2008'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: personNameList,
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    'Population in 2008: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +
                    ' millions';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: dataList,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML code too? Or post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: @JEES : here is the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

Comment: Well I see two the same images, so what is the difference?

Comment: @SebastianBochan : notice the vertical data range , first one had data range values right in front of the line , but what i want is the data ranges to exist between the range lines , as in second image

Comment: Indeed, but could you supply your example ? which browser do you use?

Comment: the example is , http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/ , i just want the data range on y axis to be in between the lines , i am using chrome and mozila , but want this to be working with every browser , IE can be neglected

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

In your `labels` object within the highcharts object, set the y position, and get rid of the '0' like this:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        if (this.value != 0) {
            return this.value; 
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    y: 40
}
```

Using this property, you can change the position [up or down] that each label is positioned. The only down-side to this is that the 0 on the y axis should be removed.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F55Zp/)